# Assets missing after deploying on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm new to RoR and after deploying I lose my assets. I tried pre-compiling assets locally, restarting the production server, deleting the app and reinstalling it again. None of these seemed to help. It works on development servers just fine.

Comment: try adding that file to your git: `git add .`

Comment: Are you dealing with image assets? Heroku regularly purges images from your apps. - they suggest the dropbox gem if that is the case.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

They're not missing. It's likely that you're not using the `rails_12factor` gem in the `production` group in your `Gemfile`:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

As mentioned in the [Getting Started with Rails 4 article on Heroku's Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4).

Install that gem + deploy your app, and your assets should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

config/environments/production.rb

config.serve_static_assets = true